# FB User Login Place

Tags: facebook, api

Is it possible to get the login locations of Facebook users through the Facebook API or without authenticating as anyone?

For example, I want to know whether a user has logged in from a particular place. All I have is the URL of this user's public profile.

Comment: This is certainly possible, I recently opted out location of user. In the world of uncertainty everything is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't - imagine the security implications if you can find out where anyone using Facebook has been logging in from.

This is common sense.

Comment: @Ed Hinchliffe, Let me know when do you need this code. This is possible if you bet in thousands of dollars.